# Why do we sometimes use the entire particles energy and sometimes only the kinetic term to express a particles wavelength?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, waves, wavefunction

In the relativisitc case, the de Broglie wavelength formula can be derived in the following way:
$$\gamma E_0=\hbar\omega=h\frac{c}{\lambda}\rightarrow\lambda=\frac{hc}{\gamma E_0}$$
In the classical case however, instead of using the entire energy contained within a particlce (including the rest energy), we only use the kinetic term. If I were to analogously derive the relativistic De Broglie wavelength, using the kinetic energy only, I would get the formula
$$\lambda=\frac{hc}{(\gamma-1)E_0},$$
which is obviously different from the earlier result. My question is, why do we sometimes only use the kinetic energy term when deriving the deBroglie wavelength and sometimes the entire energy contained within?

Answer (score 0):

A little Base:

The de Broglie equations relate the wavelength $ λ $ to the momentum $p$, and frequency $f$ to the total energy $E$ of a free particle

$$\lambda=\frac{h}{p}$$
$$f=\frac{E}{h}$$

In relativistic case, when momentum $p=\gamma m_0v$ and $E=\gamma m_0c^2$ We have
$$\lambda=\frac{h}{\gamma m_0 v}$$

and $$f=\frac{\gamma m_0c^2}{c}$$

---

> In the classical case, however, instead of using the entire energy contained within a particle (including the rest energy), we only use the kinetic term.

This is true.  We know that
$$E^2=(pc)^2+(m_0c^2)^2$$

As in the case of classical mechanics $v<<c$ so that
$$E=\frac{1}{2}m_0v^2+m_0c^2$$

and momentum reduces to $p=m_0v$ So that
$$p^2=2mK^2$$
works. But If you do the same for the relativistic case, it won't because of the relation between relativistic momentum and kinetic energy.

$$K=(\gamma-1)m_0c^2=E-m_0c^2$$
and $$E^2=(pc)^2+(m_0c^2)^2$$

If you want to work with Kinetic energy you need to find a relation between $p$ and $K$ and then use the de Broglie relation.

---

In your calculation, You have used something from relativistic mechanics and something from classical which is wrong.

Comment: It just occurred to me that for the wavelength you only need the impulse, which is obiously only dependent on the kinetic energy. How would you however calculate the frequency of a matter wave non-relativistically? On one hand we could use the formula $$f=E/h$$, on the other, we could relate frequency and wavelength using $$c=\lambda f$$. I dont see how both ways to calculate it should be equivalent, since one requires the rest mass to be known and the other doesnt.

Comment: Furthermore, when discussing a particle with zero kinetic energy, its total energy converges towards its rest energy. $$f=\frac{E}{h}=\frac{E_0}{h}$$ If we were to use the relations $$c=\lambda f$$ and $$\lambda = \frac{h}{p}$$ we can easily see that the frequency must converge to 0, which is not equal to $$f=\frac{E_0}{h}$$ According to this equation a particle should even have a wavelength if its not in motion. This problem leads me to believe that the equation $c=\lambda f$ is not true for matter waves, which confuses me, since I thought that $c=\lambda f$ holds true for all kind of waves.

Comment: The expression $\lambda f= c $ holds only for em waves.

Comment: While the relation $\mathbf{p}=\hbar \mathbf{k}$ is valid for matter waves.  see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_particle

Comment: sorry, I meant $v=\lambda f$ not $c$

Comment: If this relation is not true for matter waves, how would I calculate the frequency of a matter wave non relativistically?

Comment: As I said for matter wave $E=\hbar \omega \Rightarrow f=E/h$ as $\omega =2\pi f$

Comment: For the non-relativistic case, the energy is just $E=p^2m$. See the Wikipedia for a sec.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116762/discussion-between-susp1cious-and-young-kindaichi).